# Python script to parse and write to multiple xml files

Tags: python, xml

Need help on the script below to perform change of the color tag of multiple XML files.

Current script only opens files but doesn't change the XML file.

```
<Data>
<Maker>VW
<Type>Passat
</Type>
<GEN>4
</GEN>
</Maker>
<Year>2010
</Year>
<Color>Blue
</Color>
<Insurance>yes
</Insurance>
</Data>
```

The Python script below:

1. Checks the XML data.
2. Finds the color blue tag and swaps it with green color.
3. Completes this edit for hundreds of files.

---

```
import os, sys
from lxml import etree
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root=tk.Tk()
# show file dialog without Tkinter window`
root.withdraw()

# Specify's directory to be read`
dirSelected = filedialog.askdirectory()
counter = 0
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dirSelected):
    for special_file in files:
        if special_file.startswith('test'):
            xml_file = etree.parse(special_file)
            for elem in xml_file.xpath(".//Color"):
                if elem.text == 'Blue':
                    elem.text = 'Green'
            xml_file.write(special_file)
```

No output from the current script.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Added additional information. The script doesn't edit the xml files from 'blue' to 'green'

Comment: In example, `elem.text` would be `'Blue\n'` not `'Blue'` so the comparison will fail.

Comment: With `'Blue\n'` the raw xml file is still not changed to `'Green'`

Comment: So maybe it is `\r\n`.  `print(repr(elem.text))` to find out, or just use `elem.text = elem.text.replace('Blue','Green')` regardless of exact format of the string.